# HTML Input Type?

Tags: html

is there any special input type in HTML that is designed to only display values, based on say, other input? When nobody is allowed to write into it. Or is a disabled text box the best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

The `readonly` attribute does your magic.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays its very easy to remove readonly attribute on browser. I suggested you to use label or span and write few lines of css codes for that label element to become look like input box.

```xml
<label>test value</label>

<style>
label {
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the readonly attribute, or use javascript to update the contents of a div

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 drafts, the `output` element exists for such purposes. I don’t think there’s much point in using it, though, since the same goal can be achieved in other ways.

In order to just display data, use any normal HTML element, like `p` or `div` or `span`.

If the data needs to be transmitted along the form data, put it into a hidden element, `<input type=hidden>`.

You can of course combine the two if needed: separately display the data and include it into the form data set.